# Which NLP methods use gradient and activation methods?

Tags: natural-language, gradient, activation-function

I am doing a literature review of gradient-based methods for NLP. Yet, apart from linear and logistic regression, I have little knowledge of other methods using the gradient. So I have no knowledge of methods using gradient-based methods for NLP. From what I have read I have decided to search in three directions (gradient based methods using 1. activation 2. hidden state 3. integrated gradient). So my question is : **"Which NLP methods use gradient and activation methods?"**

Browsing for "gradient" and "activation" I've only found [*Gradient-weighted Class Activation Mapping (Grad-CAM)*](https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-your-algorithm-with-grad-cam-d3b62fce353) so far, the example is on Computer Vision (and there is a disclaimer on the Medium article that *the Grad-CAM can be difficult to wrap your head around* ;p)

PS: let me know if this question is more suitable to Data science site.

Comment: Aren’t all of the deep learning approaches part of this?

Comment: I thought so @Dave ! Before I read [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-fascinating-no-gradient-approach-to-neural-net-optimization-abb287f88c97) about no-gradient approach to neural net optimization like *Particle Swarm Optimization*, a population-based method that defines a set of ‘particles’ that explore the search space, attempting to find a minimum without gradient, or the more well known *Surrogate optimization* a method of optimization that attempts to model the loss function with another well-established function to find the minima. So I'm looking for all the others...